# PulseAudio set permanent configuration with a virtual source

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

My system has a 6-channel USB microphone and a software that is recording audio. I must ensure that if USB mic is available(plugged), the first channel of it will be used by the program for the audio recording.

Mic could be unavailable for some period (unplugged). When it is plugged again, I must ensure that the program uses the recently plugged mic. The internal audio IC appears as a source device in use when our external mic is unavailable(but it can't record because there is no mic on 3.5mm audio jack).

The mic has 6 channels named front-left, front-right, rear-left and etc. front-left is the desired channel. I used module-remap-source to create a virtual source and set it as a default:

```
pactl load-module module-remap-source master=alsa_input.MIC_NAME.multichannel-input master_channel_map=front-left channel_map=front-left remix=false

pactl set-default-source alsa_input.MIC_NAME.multichannel_input.remapped
```

If I start the program after these commands, everything works fine.

The Problem:

The USB microphone could be attached and detached by the user at any time during run-time. When mic is detached and attached again, the virtual source with single channel disappears. I need to re-run the above written commands. **Is there a way to make this virtual source permanent?**

**Also, I would appreciate any tips on how to restart the audio software once mic is detected so that it uses correct source(or ensure that software switched to correct source)**

It is a closed system, Ubuntu Server with no Mouse/Keyboard/Display. System must be able to understand these events by itself.

Comment: Add a null sink, using the associated `.monitor` source as permanent source. Use module-loopback to play front-left to the null sink (I don't know if you need to manually restart that when you replug, possible you can use udev). No need to restart audio software, it will just record silence from the null sink monitor when USB is absent.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Very sorry for late reply. In the end design changed so that mic won't be unplugged ever. I wrote a service that automatically creates virtual source and sets is as a default every time device is turned on.